# How to fix simple HAProxy logging

Tags: haproxy, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and I am wondering how I can log everything that happens in HAProxy. I've been reading issues concerning logging and chroot. Everything is telling me to do write different things in different files.

```
/var/log# ls
alternatives.log  apt  bootstrap.log  btmp  dmesg  dpkg.log  faillog  fsck  lastlog  upstart  wtmp

/etc/rsyslog.d# ls
49-haproxy.conf  50-default.conf
```

My `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` file contains this:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    maxconn 2048
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  10000
    timeout server  10000
```

I can't seem to see any logs anywhere!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
global
    log /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log local0 debug
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy

frontend
    log /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log local4 debug
```

`/dev/log` did not exist. The socket was located at `/var/lib/haproxy/dev/log`.

`49-haproxy.conf` file:

```
local0.* -/var/log/haproxy/haproxy_0.log
local4.* -/var/log/haproxy/haproxy_4.log
if ($programname == 'haproxy') then -/var/log/haproxy/haproxy.log
& ~
```

Then simple kill and start:

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog start
/etc/init.d/haproxy start
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to have set the socket with the right owner:

```
chmod haproxy:haproxy /var/lib/haproxy/dev/log
```

Comment: This does not look like a path to a socket.